# Simple query SQLite android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created a database that includes a table with 3 columns. 
[ID Date FCode ZCode].

```
    // Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CODES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + KEY_DATE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_FCODE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_ZCODE + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CODES_TABLE);
}
```

I have manages to communicate with the SQLite database but i have a problem returning some values from the DB. More precisely, i am inserting some information in the Database like :

```
    db.addSQLinfo(new SQLCodes("01-07-2016", "100", "200"));
    db.addSQLinfo(new SQLCodes("02-07-2016", "101", "201"));
    db.addSQLinfo(new SQLCodes("03-07-2016", "102", "202"));
    db.addSQLinfo(new SQLCodes("04-07-2016", "103", "203"));
    db.addSQLinfo(new SQLCodes("05-07-2016", "104", "204"));
    db.addSQLinfo(new SQLCodes("06-07-2016", "105", "205"));
    db.addSQLinfo(new SQLCodes("07-07-2016", "106", "206"));
```

and later on i am using this query to retrieve the Data. My target is to return all the values based on the date that i set. So for example if i execute this :

```
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(
            TABLE_NAME, new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_DATE, KEY_FCODE, KEY_ZCODE},
            "05-07-2016", null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToNext();

    String[] infos = {
            cursor.getString(0),   // return KEY_ID
            cursor.getString(1),   // return KEY_DATE
            cursor.getString(2),   // return KEY_FCODE
            cursor.getString(3)    // return KEY_ZCODE
    };
```

infos String[] array always has [1, 01-07-2016, 100, 200] no matter the  Date that i set in db.query. I tried several other Query methods but with no results.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM TAB WHERE 05-07-2016` what it supposed to mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have missed out a parameter.

The 3rd paremeter is the column name you wish to check against?
and the 4th the value you wish to check for.

It should read:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(
        TABLE_NAME, new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_DATE, KEY_FCODE, KEY_ZCODE},
        KEY_DATE + "= ?", new String[] {"05-07-2016"}, null, null, null);
```

Comment: @monakons As per your example, you are trying to find data for that given day. So that would be correct yes. If you are trying to pass in a date as a parameter, you would obviously need to change the hardcoded string `"05-07-2016"` to your date string parameter.

Comment: The hardcoded string is a simplified version of the code, of course i use a parameter on a function to do this, but this is unrelated with the question.

Comment: @monakons Can you expand on how the above is not the answer to the question you asked? Else I am unable to help. The above should be giving you the desired functionality

Comment: The string parameter in the query, either is hardcoded or a function parameter is still a string. The problem is in the query not the string itself.

Comment: @monakons I think you may have mis-read my answer. I added an extra parameter, that builds a proper query. Rather than your example. Regardless of the date string as you said. You need to add the parameter `KEY_DATE + "= ?"`

Comment: oops sorry i mis-read the answer indeed. Thanks, your answer is correct!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116169/discussion-between-monakons-and-doomsknight).